# How can I pull the facebook pages that my fans like

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-page

Based on this [this](http://www.google.ro/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http://socialmediatoday.com/jonbarilone/280538/facebook-page-cheat-find-out-what-your-fans&ei=yT2ATvq1BoKR0QWbteXPCQ&usg=AFQjCNF_2fD7oXLxFk9hxEOrndbitDjKyw&sig2=2nMh4dSQYuqhKKWNeKj4JQ) article, let's say that I manage FB page "A". When I'm logged into Facebook as "Page A" I'm seeing on the right sidebar under *Recommended Pages*, a few Pages that my fans like. Because this info is very useful, I want to pull all the pages that my fans like automatically. Any ideas on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have them authorise an application you write and grant you the `user_likes` permission.

You can then access the list of pages they like from the `/{user id}/likes` endpoint of the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

Answer (score 0):

```
FB.api('/me/likes',function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

This will give you all the user's like in an array, with ids etc.